# Ionic 3 , how to display certain images when clicking certain item on another page

Tags: html, typescript, ionic-framework

I need help on how to display certain image(slider)which is on gallery.html, example when clicking January edition on eighteen.html, it only displays January edition on gallery.html while February and March edition is hidden. Its been 2 days, I had no luck on how to do it and I am new on ionic.

this is my code eighteen.ts and below it is the HTML.

```js
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { IonicPage, NavController, NavParams } from 'ionic-angular';
import { GalleryPage } from '../gallery/gallery';

/**
 * Generated class for the EighteenPage page.
 *
 * See https://ionicframework.com/docs/components/#navigation for more info on
 * Ionic pages and navigation.
 */

@IonicPage()
@Component({
  selector: 'page-eighteen',
  templateUrl: 'eighteen.html',
})
export class EighteenPage {

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public navParams: NavParams) {
  }

  ionViewDidLoad() {
    console.log('ionViewDidLoad EighteenPage');
  }

toGalleryPage(){
this.navCtrl.push(GalleryPage);
}

}
```

```html
<ion-content>
<ion-grid>
      <ion-row>

          <ion-col col-6 col-md-4 col-xl-3>

            <img (click)="toGalleryPage(1)" src="assets/imgs/year2018/bhcmagazine-january2018.jpg">
            <p>January</p>
          </ion-col>
  
          <ion-col col-6 col-md-4 col-xl-3>

           <img (click)="toGalleryPage(2)" src="assets/imgs/year2018/bhcmagazine-february2018.jpg">
            <p>February</p>

          </ion-col>
  
          <ion-col col-6 col-md-4 col-xl-3>
  
            <img (click)="toGalleryPage(3)" src="assets/imgs/year2018/bhcmagazine-mac2018.jpg">
            <p>March</p>

          </ion-col>

      </ion-row>
</ion-grid>
</ion-content>
```

This are the gallery.ts and gallery.html.

```js
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { IonicPage, NavController, NavParams } from 'ionic-angular';


@IonicPage()
@Component({
  selector: 'page-gallery',
  templateUrl: 'gallery.html',
})
export class GalleryPage {
  imagesjan = [
    'January-2018_Web-page-001.jpg',
    'January-2018_Web-page-002.jpg',
    'January-2018_Web-page-003.jpg',
    'January-2018_Web-page-004.jpg',
    'January-2018_Web-page-005.jpg'


  ];
  imagesfeb = [
    'Februray-2018_Web-page-001.jpg', 
    'Februray-2018_Web-page-002.jpg', 
    'Februray-2018_Web-page-003.jpg', 
    'Februray-2018_Web-page-004.jpg',
    'Februray-2018_Web-page-005.jpg'

  ];

  imagesmarch =[
    'Mac-2018_Web-page-001.jpg', 
    'Mac-2018_Web-page-002.jpg', 
    'Mac-2018_Web-page-003.jpg', 
    'Mac-2018_Web-page-004.jpg',
    'Mac-2018_Web-page-005.jpg'
  ];
  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public navParams: NavParams) {
  }

  ionViewDidLoad() {
    console.log('ionViewDidLoad GalleryPage');
  }

}
```

```html
<ion-header>

  <ion-navbar>
    <ion-title>gallery</ion-title>
  </ion-navbar>

</ion-header>


<ion-content>
    <ion-slides id="1" pager="true" class="image-slider-01" loop="true">
        <ion-slide *ngFor="let img of imagesjan">
          <img src="assets/imgs/year2018/january/{{img}}" class="thumb-img" imageViewer="assets/imgs/year2018/january/{{img}}"/> 
          <p>January Edition 2018</p>
        </ion-slide>
    </ion-slides>

   <ion-slides id="2" pager="true" class="image-slider-02" loop="true">
        <ion-slide *ngFor="let img of imagesfeb">
          <img src="assets/imgs/year2018/february/{{img}}" class="thumb-img" imageViewer="assets/imgs/year2018/february/{{img}}"/>
          <p>February Edition 2018</p>
        </ion-slide>
        
    </ion-slides>
    
    <ion-slides id="3" pager="true" class="image-slider-03" loop="true">
        <ion-slide *ngFor="let img of imagesmarch">
          <img src="assets/imgs/year2018/march/{{img}}" class="thumb-img" imageViewer="assets/imgs/year2018/march/{{img}}"/>
          <p>March Edition 2018</p>
        </ion-slide>
        
    </ion-slides>
</ion-content>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Need to change your code following step:

In eighteen.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { IonicPage, NavController, NavParams } from 'ionic-angular';
import { GalleryPage } from '../gallery/gallery';

/**
 * Generated class for the EighteenPage page.
 *
 * See https://ionicframework.com/docs/components/#navigation for more info on
 * Ionic pages and navigation.
 */

@IonicPage()
@Component({
  selector: 'page-eighteen',
  templateUrl: 'eighteen.html',
})
export class EighteenPage {

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public navParams: NavParams) {
  }

  ionViewDidLoad() {
    console.log('ionViewDidLoad EighteenPage');
  }

toGalleryPage(id){
  this.navCtrl.push(GalleryPage,{id: id});
}

}
```

In eighteen.html need not change

In gallery.ts need to change following

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { IonicPage, NavController, NavParams } from 'ionic-angular';


@IonicPage()
@Component({
  selector: 'page-gallery',
  templateUrl: 'gallery.html',
})
export class GalleryPage {
  private id:any;

  imagesjan = [
    'January-2018_Web-page-001.jpg',
    'January-2018_Web-page-002.jpg',
    'January-2018_Web-page-003.jpg',
    'January-2018_Web-page-004.jpg',
    'January-2018_Web-page-005.jpg'
  ];

  imagesfeb = [
    'Februray-2018_Web-page-001.jpg', 
    'Februray-2018_Web-page-002.jpg', 
    'Februray-2018_Web-page-003.jpg', 
    'Februray-2018_Web-page-004.jpg',
    'Februray-2018_Web-page-005.jpg'

  ];

  imagesmarch =[
    'Mac-2018_Web-page-001.jpg', 
    'Mac-2018_Web-page-002.jpg', 
    'Mac-2018_Web-page-003.jpg', 
    'Mac-2018_Web-page-004.jpg',
    'Mac-2018_Web-page-005.jpg'
  ];

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public navParams: NavParams) {
     this.id= navParams.get("id");
  }

  ionViewDidLoad() {
    console.log('ionViewDidLoad GalleryPage');
  }

}
```

In gallery.html need to change following

```
<ion-header>

  <ion-navbar>
    <ion-title>gallery</ion-title>
  </ion-navbar>

</ion-header>


<ion-content>
    <ion-slides id="1" pager="true" class="image-slider-01" loop="true" *ngIf="id == 1">
        <ion-slide *ngFor="let img of imagesjan">
          <img src="assets/imgs/year2018/january/{{img}}" class="thumb-img" imageViewer="assets/imgs/year2018/january/{{img}}"/> 
          <p>January Edition 2018</p>
        </ion-slide>
    </ion-slides>

   <ion-slides id="2" pager="true" class="image-slider-02" loop="true" *ngIf="id == 2">
        <ion-slide *ngFor="let img of imagesfeb">
          <img src="assets/imgs/year2018/february/{{img}}" class="thumb-img" imageViewer="assets/imgs/year2018/february/{{img}}"/>
          <p>February Edition 2018</p>
        </ion-slide>

    </ion-slides>

    <ion-slides id="3" pager="true" class="image-slider-03" loop="true" *ngIf="id == 3">
        <ion-slide *ngFor="let img of imagesmarch">
          <img src="assets/imgs/year2018/march/{{img}}" class="thumb-img" imageViewer="assets/imgs/year2018/march/{{img}}"/>
          <p>March Edition 2018</p>
        </ion-slide>

    </ion-slides>
</ion-content>
```